Give or take one
How many points should the first country get? Why?
        Small Catalan speaking country (7)                        ? points
        Small country in the horn of Africa (8)                        8 points
        Mountainous country in central America (9)                      5 points
        Country with the highest-valued currency in the world (6)      2 points
        Country neighbouring Belgium (10)                              10 points
        Large country south of US (6)                                  2 points
        Small country bordering France (6)                             6 points
        South American country known for its canal (6)                2 points
        Small country bordering Italy (3)(6)                           9 points
        Country where the equator passes through (3) (4) (3) (8)       7 points
        Mandarin speaking country (9)                                  9 points
        Very small country known for their religious leader (7) (4)    11 points


I believe the answer is

 0

My reasoning:

 All clues (except one) lead to country who's capital city is either the same as the country or contains additional words. In all cases, the number of points is the number of letters in the country minus the number of extra letters in the capital city. 
 The answer to the first question is Andorra whose capital city is Andorra La Vella. The sum is thus len("Andorra") - len("LaVella") = 7 - 7 = 0

Note that:

 My logic fails with Sao Tome And Principe. I can't quite see the full pattern in all clues which would give a score of points for this country


Well done, thats the answer! rot13(Gur ybtvp jnf gung rirel pncvgny fgnegf jvgu gur fnzr anzr/yrggref nf gur pbhagevrf. +1 sbe rnpu yrggre naq -1 sbe rnpu rkgen yrggref (tvir be gnxr bar nf gur gvgyr fnlf). Fb gur pncvgny Fnb Gbzr trgf frira cbvagf orpnhfr bs gur frira fgnegvat yrggref bs Fnb Gbzr naq Cevapvcr (jvgu ab erqhpgvba orpnhfr gurer ner ab yrggref nsgre gur pncvgny Fnb Gbzr)

Presumably you have the list of the countries and their capitals - why didn't you include it in the answer? Explaining an answer clue by clue is typical here.
